# find -exec with two commands (gdalinfo and jq)

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to concatenate two processes after `find` command in shell; my intention is to find certain GeoTiff files and to get their area by subtracting non-null count from width*height, first part is done in `gdalinfo` and latter with `jq` on the json,

I can pipe them together for one single file:

`gdalinfo -json -hist odm_orthophoto.tif | jq '.size[0]*.size[1]-.bands[0].histogram.buckets[0]'`

But with `find` function it apparently pays no attention to the second `-exec`

`find . -name "odm_orthophoto.tif" -exec gdalinfo -json -hist  {} \; -exec jq '.size[0]*.size[1]-.bands[0].histogram.buckets[0]' {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

Like this (this will be very difficult to concatenate 2 find -exec commands if you have more than 1 file):

```
find . -name "odm_orthophoto.tif" -exec bash -c '
    for file; do
        {
            gdalinfo -json -hist "$file"
            jq ".size[0]*.size[1]-.bands[0].histogram.buckets[0]" "$file"
        } | tee "new_$file"
    done
' -- {} +
```

Then:

```
ls -ltr new_*
```

See [using find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)

Comment: That command was failing due to some exceptions (I know you don't have the same files to try) .Thanks for leading me to for, I don't know why I was so into using `find`; the line i, after writing the output of `find`: wrote was: `for i in $(cat ortofotos.txt); do gdalinfo -json -hist $i | jq '.size[0]*.size[1]-.bands[0].histogram.buckets[0]'; done`

Comment: Can you please add another question with this new code ?

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for next times

Comment: Do you mean to post a new question or another answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, with your `for loop` that need to be enhanced